Issue with errorbar series not respecting inactive state settings in Highcharts
I am currently developing a chart using Highcharts and I've encountered an issue related to the errorbar series type.
My goal is to create a column chart where each column has associated minimum and maximum values displayed, using an errorbar to do so.
I am trying to have a visual effect where hovering over a column reduces the opacity of all other columns and their associated error bars to enhance focus on the active column.
To do this, I am using the inactiveOtherPoints field on my series.
While the inactiveOtherPoints: true property works as expected for the column series (diminishing the opacity of non-hovered columns to 50%), the errorbar series linked to these columns do not respond to the inactive state settings.
I tried to change the settings for the "states" field in the errorbar series as well, but nothing seems to be working, the error bars remain fully opaque.
Here is a snippet of the relevant Highcharts configuration I am using :
You can also find the entire code in this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pg7nz8br/32/
const options: Highcharts.Options = {
  colors: avgDataSerie.colors,
  series: [
    {
      id: 'avg',
      type: avgDataSerie.type, // = "column"
      data: avgDataSerie.data,
      inactiveOtherPoints: true
    },
    {
      type: errorbarData.type, // = "errorbar"
      data: errorbarData.data,
      inactiveOtherPoints: true,
      linkedTo: 'avg'
    }],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointWidth: 60,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderRadius: 8
    },
    series: {
      animation: {
        duration: 200
      },
      inactiveOtherPoints: true,
      states: {
        inactive: {
          enabled: true,
          opacity: 0.5
        },
        hover: {
          enabled: true,
          opacity: 1.0
        }
      }
    },
    errorbar: {
      stemWidth: 2,
      whiskerWidth: 2,
      whiskerLength: 14
    }
  }
};

According to the documentation, the states property should also be applicable to errorbar series, but it seems not to be recognized.
Have you encountered this issue before, and do you have any recommendations or workarounds that might help resolve this problem?
Thank you for your assistance.

It is hard to tell you what could be done without taking a look at your entire code. Could you reproduce the issue in an online editor that I could work on?  You can use this demo as a template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0s7phkfx/

Thank you for your answer, I edited my post with a JSFiddle with the entire code.

I added an answer, hope it helps!

That's great to hear!

You can use mouseOver and mouseOut function in which:

In mouseOver function you can gray out points that are on the different X-axis parameter than the hovered point

In mouseOut function you can restore the opacity of all points to 1
point: {
 events: {
  mouseOver: function() {
   const pointX = this.x;
   this.series.chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
     series.points.forEach(function(point) {
       if (point.x !== pointX) {
         point.graphic.attr({
           opacity: 0.3
         });
       }
     });
   });
 },
  mouseOut: function() {
   this.series.chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
     series.points.forEach(function(point) {
       point.graphic.attr({
         opacity: 1
       });
     });
   });
  }
 }
}



API references:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t17b5ukL/
